# Rewrite query with union in subquery by using gorm

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to write sql query by using gorm. Here the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(tags) as tag_name FROM models
        union all
    SELECT unnest(system_tags) from models
left join projects on projects.id = models.project_id 
WHERE (projects.is_public = true )) as tD 
WHERE LOWER( tD.tag_name ) LIKE '%12%' ORDER BY tag_name
```

I tried to create subquery. But cant figure out how to add union. As I understand select does not work this way. Is using Raw() my only option?

```
selectStr := "unnest(tags) as tag_name from models union select unnest(system_tags) from models"

subQuery = db.
    Model(&tagsGet).
    Select(selectStr).
    Joins(joinStrProjects).
    Where(whereClause, args...)
```